# How to hang a button with html and css

Tags: html, css

I have a regular button right under navigation bar with around `150px` space from nav and I wanted it to look like a banner:

**Button:**

[image]

**What I want:** (something similar to this)

[image]

I just want to draw 2 lines meeting at single point on top and at two points in the button.

I am not sure, if it is possible or not? Any type of guide would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using canvas

Comment: Yes its possible. But you'll need more than a button. Clearly.

Comment: @Rishi any example?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan example or reference?

Comment: Will post an answer

Comment: so two ropes = two elements. Right? Have you googled how to CSS rotate an element? You should show your best try before asking for help. StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a couple of svg lines above the button:

https://jsfiddle.net/1sj0qzvL/

HTML

```
<div class="hanger">
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <line x1="10" y1="100" x2="100" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <circle cx="10" cy="100" r=5 fill="red" />
  </svg>
  <svg height="100" width="100">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="90" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <circle cx="90" cy="100" r=5 fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="button-inner">
    BUTTON TO HANG!
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hanger {
   margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.button {
  border: 4px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-inner {
  color: red;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of hanging it with gravity in canvas:

```js
var ctx;

window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  update();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(250,250);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(500,0);
  ctx.lineTo(250,250);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 210px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

body: {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hanging button example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <button>Click me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can increase the functionality by using phaser.js and us gravity or other features. You can also draw the button in the canvas, but without gravity, this is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!